# A faster way to do sums?

Tags: summation

I found out that,it is INCREDIBLY(like 100 times) faster to use  `Dot` instead of `Sum`,to perform long sums. But I have not been able to use this alternative to perform the following sum:

```
a={{b,c},{d,e}};

a[[1]]+a[[2]]
```

I want to get this output:

> ```
> {b,c}+{d,e}={b+d,c+e}
> ```

I tried:

```
a.{1,1}
```

but did not work.

The easy way to do it is:

```
Sum[a[[i]],{i,1,2}];
```

But I want to avoid this slow way. Any faster alternative?

Comment: Have you looked at using `Total`?

Comment: NO did not. I will try that...

Comment: @chuy Actually it's just `Total[a]` in this case.  What your input does is more simply done as `Total[a, {2}]`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Sum` is meant for working with symbolic sums (check the examples in the docs to see what I mean).  What you are looking for here is `Total`:

```
Total[a]

(* ==> {b+d,c+e} *)
```

Before we had this shorthand, we used `Plus` with `Apply`:

```
Plus @@ a

(* ==> {b+d,c+e} *)
```

---

The most important difference between using `Total` and `Plus` is that `Total` is optimized for performance.  `Plus` will always do [compensated summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensated_summation) while this needs to be explicitly turned on in `Total` using `Method -> CompensatedSummation`.

Both can be used at various [levels or ranges of levels](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html).  Compare `Total[a, {2}]` with `Apply[Plus, a, {1}]`.

Comment: Good ol´ times, eh? I find `Plus@@a` also especially educational...

Comment: It seems that `Plus` is not entirely equivalent to `Total` with compensated summation, ref: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103771/121

Answer (score 7):

Or, in keeping with the request to use `Dot`, you can restate it as a vector/matrix product

```
{1, 1}.a

{b+d,c+e}
```