# Compilation of Total with compensated summation

Tags: compile, warning-messages, machine-precision

I sometimes obtain an unexpected error when trying to call a compiled version of `Total` with compensated summation turned on. More specifically I define

```
f1 = Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},Total[x],CompilationTarget->"C"];
f2 = Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},Total[x,Method->"CompensatedSummation"],CompilationTarget->"C"];
```

When I call the functions via

```
x=RandomReal[{0,1},10^5]
f1[x]
f2[x]
```

I sometimes, but not always, obtain a `CompiledFunction::cfte` error, informing me that the

> "Compiled expression [some large number of order $10^{5}$] should be a
>   rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers."

I have studied the documentation of that error but have been unable to isolate the problem any further. The results of `f1` and `f2` differ by up to $1\times 10^{-9}$ and the difference becomes even larger for larger input vectors, so I'd quite like to be able to use the (presumably more accurate) version with compensated summation turned on.

**Question**: What causes the `CompiledFunction::cfte` error and how can I avoid it when compiling `Total` with compensated summation?

In case it matters I am using version 9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: Looks like it *might* be a bug - I note that repeated calls with same argument eventually result in return with no error. Strange. Note also, however, that calling `Total` with `CompensatedSummation` results in a jump out to `MainEvaluate`, so any performance benefits to compiling `Total` get quashed.

Comment: Compensated summation does indeed make a difference: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62917/why-does-taking-advantage-of-listable-change-the-results-of-a-numerical-computat/62929#62929

Answer (score 16):

### Compilation of Total

As pointed out in a comment, it seems that the compensated summation form of `Total` can't be compiled. You can check this using `CompilePrint` - note the call to `MainEvaluate`.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint@f2  (* from your question *)
```

---

### Summation in Mathematica

There seem to be plenty of options for summing a list in Mathematica. For example, you can use `Plus`, which apparently [will always do compensated summation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31731/13162), or `Tr[]`, [inspired by this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63209/total-much-slower-in-version-10).

```
uncompiledTotal[x_] := Total[x];
compiledTotal = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
compensatedTotal[x_] := Total[x, Method -> "CompensatedSummation"];

plus[x_] := Apply[Plus, x];
compiledPlus = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Apply[Plus,x], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

uncompiledTr[x_] := Tr[x];
```

---

### Compiled Kahan summation

There is another option, of course, which is to make your own machine-precision compiled implementation of [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

```
kahanSummation = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}},
  Module[{s, c, y, t, i},
   s = 0.;
   c = 0.;
   For[i = 1, i <= Length@x, i++,
     y = x[[i]] - c;
     t = s + y;
     c = (t - s) - y;
     s = t;];
   s],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

---

### Comparison: Accuracy

Now let's test the performance of these options, first in terms of the actual result, compared to the built-in compensated summation method (which I assume to be correct).

```
x = N@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^6];
TableForm[MapThread[{#1, NumberForm[Abs[#2 - compensatedTotal[x]], 16]} &,
   {{"Uncompiled total", "Compiled total", "Compensated summation", 
     "Kahan summation", "Uncompiled plus", "Compiled plus", "Uncompiled Tr"},
    {uncompiledTotal[x], compiledTotal[x], compensatedTotal[x], 
     kahanSummation[x], plus[x], compiledPlus[x], uncompiledTr[x]}}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Function", "Error"}}]
```

[image]

Clearly the behaviours of both `Total` and `Plus` depend on whether they are compiled or not. The key thing to note here is that the above compiled implementation of `kahanSummation[]` gives the same result as Mathematica's own compensated summation approach.

Graphically, we can use the code from [ybeltukov's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/62929/13162) to look at the residuals. See if you can spot the difference between my compiled Kahan method and the built-in!

[image]

---

### Comparison: Speed

Finally, it's also worth comparing the timings of each of the methods above, since that's typically a reason to use `Compile[]` in the first place.

[image]

The compiled implementation of `kahanSummation[]` is much faster than either `Plus` or `Total` with compensated summation, and the extra operations it utilises are only a small performance hit compared to the built-in implementation of `Total`.

Comment: Very interesting. I must admit I'm surprised that `Total` doesn't use compensated summation by default, given that it is an RTL call from the VM, and that it is so much slower than the straightforward implementation.

Comment: @OleksandrR. indeed, I was surprised it was so much slower (20x?) when compensated summation is turned on. Also curious about the changes when `Plus` and `Total` are compiled.