# Kahan Compensated Summation

Tags: matrix, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

Is there an example/library that implements Kahan summation in Mathematica for matrix-matrix/vector-matrix multiplication?

Having some trouble adapting something like this [Compilation of Total with compensated summation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79174/compilation-of-total-with-compensated-summation) for these cases.

Comment: Please add an example in MMA code that leads to troublesome results when run without compensated summation. It would also be helpful to show how you tried to use `Total[..., Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]` so we can see what may have gone wrong.