# How does Plus work on machine precision Real arguments?

Tags: numerics, core-language, implementation-details, arithmetic

I thought Kahan's summation method would make a nice example for students to use to think about round-off error
[[W. Kahan,
Pracniques: Further Remarks on Reducing Truncation Errors,
*Commun. ACM* **8**  (1965), 40](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/363707.363723)].  The method is available (I surmise) through the option `Method -> "CompensatedSummation"` of [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html), but it's an easy program to write that is nicely laid out in the half-page article.

Below the vector `x0` is a list whose elements are to be added. Note that `s0` is the "exact" sum, that is, the sum of the exact numbers represented by the floating-point numbers in `x0`, rounded to machine precision.  I consider it the target of the summation methods below.

```
SeedRandom[2];
x0 = 2 + RandomReal[1, 1000000];
s0 = N@Total[SetPrecision[x0, Infinity]];
```

Here is a norm (with sign) that measures the relative error in `x - x0` in units of `$MachineEpsilon`.

```
meps[x_, x0_, eps_: $MachineEpsilon] := ((x - x0)/x0)/eps;
```

Then here are some ways to add up the vector. The timings are not particularly important, but they're somewhat interesting.  I unpack `x0` before apply `Plus`, since it would be unpacked anyway by `Apply` (`@@`), in order that the unpacking not be included in the timing; the sum is the same we would get with `Plus @@ x0`.

```
{With[{x0 = Developer`FromPackedArray[x0]}, 
   sP = Plus @@ x0; // AbsoluteTiming],
  sF = Fold[Plus, x0]; // AbsoluteTiming,
  sT = Total[x0]; // AbsoluteTiming,
  sC = Total[x0, Method -> "CompensatedSummation"]; // AbsoluteTiming
  }[[All, 1]]
(*  {0.131215, 0.120635, 0.000571, 0.01399}  *)
```

The example was chosen to show that `Plus` does something nearly like compensated summation but not exactly the same.

```
meps[{sP, sF, sT, sC}, s0]
(*  Plus       Fold     Total     Compensated  Version
   {-0.838972, 149.337, -56.2111, 0.}          10.4.1
   {-0.838972, 149.337, -2.51692, 0.}          11.1.1  *)
```

Aside from being surprised that `Plus` is such a slow method, I got to wondering what `Plus` is doing.  With some effort, one can find that the order of the elements in `x0` can affect the result of `Plus`.  The only results I can find have errors of either 1 or 0 in the last bit.  They are compared to the results of iterative adding using `Fold`.

```
meps[{Plus @@ Sort@x0, Fold[Plus, Sort@x0]}, s0]
(*  {-0.838972, -33.5589}  *)

meps[{Plus @@ -Sort[-x0], Fold[Plus, -Sort[-x0]]}, s0]
(*  {-0.838972, 182.057}  *)

SeedRandom[0];
With[{x0 = RandomSample[x0]}, meps[{Plus @@ x0, Fold[Plus, x0]}, s0]]
(*  {0., -158.566}  *)

SeedRandom[1];
With[{x0 = RandomSample[x0]}, meps[{Plus @@ x0, Fold[Plus, x0]}, s0]]
(*  {-0.838972, -93.9648}  *)
```

Does anyone know how `Plus` works?  It would be nice to be able to explain it.

Comment: Might want to check on progressively larger examples to see if it scales as n log(n), that might indicate sorting under the hood. I remark that I do not know the answer offhand and probably will not have time to peek into the code to find out.

Comment: A related remark is that this runs the risk of being closed as requiring an internal developer response. All the same, an interesting question I think.

Comment: perhaps it simply uses extended (but not infinite) precision

Comment: Plus on machine doubles will not use extended precision unless there is an overflow.

Comment: This is a related point about compensated summation, to an extent http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79174/compilation-of-total-with-compensated-summation

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Seems slightly closer to n log(n) than n; best fits are proportional to n^1.14 or (n log(n))^1.06.

Comment: @george2079 Perhaps you mean extended-precision registers on the CPU/FPU are used to accumulate the result?  That may be possible if the summand are chunked and the intermediate sums rounded to MP from time to time.  If the whole computation is done with as little as 6 extra bits, the result rounds to the "exact" 53-bit result.

Comment: If it is a matter of extended precision registers, this is likely to vary based on operating system, whether `Compile` was used somewhere, and probably a few other incidentals (like, phase of the moon).

Comment: Since `Plus` has attribute `Orderless`, it isn't surprising that `Plus @@ x0` and `Fold[Plus, x0]` produce different results. The order of arguments of `Plus` doesn't matter and expectedly `Plus @@ x0`, `Plus @@ Sort@x0`, `Plus @@ -Sort[-x0]` produce identical results.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I did check out the `Orderless` attribute: `Plus` can give different results (of at most one ulp) for different orderings of the arguments (via `RandomSample`). If the `Orderless` attribute affects evaluation, it is not by the arguments being sorted into canonical order before evaluation. It makes sense to me that orderless numerical functions like `Plus` would go directly to evaluation on numeric input.  Simple example: `Plus[1., -1., $MachineEpsilon/2]` vs. `Plus[1., $MachineEpsilon/2, -1.]`.  `Orderless` is more important for symbolic computations.

Comment: Interesting question.  Incidentally you forgot to include `Tr`, my favorite method to sum a list.  Including it in v10.1 I find it twice as fast as (plain) `Total` with the same error.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks. I forget why I omitted `Tr`. Either I overlooked it or skipped it because it gave the same error as `Total` and preferred comparing `Total` with and without compensated summation.  Interestingly in V11.1.1 (Mac/Intel), `RepeatedTiming` gives the same speed `0.25` sec for both `Total` and Tr` but repeated group timing with `AbsoluteTiming` as above gives means of `0.63` and `0.42` respectively. (I included `Fold` because I *know* how the numbers are being added in that case.)

Answer (score 2):

Following up on your own comment about chunking I was able to replicate the result of `Plus` using a simple [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) with a block size of 100,000:

```
myPlus[x__] := Total /@ Partition[{x}, 1*^5, 1*^5, 1, 0] // Total

meps[myPlus @@ x0, s0]
```

> ```
> -0.838972
> ```

Comment: Interesting, but I think it's the unpacking, not the chunking, that leads to the `Plus` result:  Any (evenly-dividing) block size works and so does plain unpacking. For instance `meps[Total[Partition[x0, 1*^6, 1*^6, 1, 0], 2], s0]` or `meps[Total[Developer`FromPackedArray@x0], s0]`. That the algorithm might depend on the data representation didn't occur to me until now. Coincidentally, I made [this possibly related observation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39144027#39144027) last night in chat.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I may have fooled myself, but I also think I lost the point of this code by using `Total[..., 2]` at the last minute.  Please see the restored definition and try other block sizes, which now for me give different results.

Comment: Okay, it's now giving me different results for different sizes.  Testing `Total[.., 2]` more extensively shows it doesn't quite always give `-0.83...` but usually does. It's still interesting to me that `Total` on the unpacked `x0` gives a different result than on the packed `x0`.